# Use sed to print matching lines

Tags: shell, unix, sed

Sample data in a stackoverflow.csv file I have:

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
bar
bar
bar
bar
baz
baz
baz
baz
```

I know with `sed -n /foo/p stackoverflow.csv > foo.csv`

I'll get all records matching foo directed to that file, but I don't want to specify the matching pattern on the cli, I'd rather put it in a script and have all records (foo, bar and baz) sent to their own file.

Basically this in a script:

```
sed -n /foo/p stackoverflow.csv > foo.csv
sed -n /bar/p stackoverflow.csv > bar.csv
sed -n /baz/p stackoverflow.csv > baz.csv
```

Like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 2
sed -n /foo/p > foo.csv
sed -n /bar/p > bar.csv
sed -n /baz/p > baz.csv
```

This creates the files but they're all empty.
Also, if the script were to have just one print statement, it works.

Any input?

Comment: What's with the `sleep 2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the input filename

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 2
sed -n /foo/p stackoverflow.csv > foo.csv
sed -n /bar/p stackoverflow.csv > bar.csv
sed -n /baz/p stackoverflow.csv > baz.csv
```

You can provide input file as an argument to your script, in that case change the script to read an argument and pass it to the `sed` command.
Run the script like this:  `./script.sh  input_filename`, where you can specify different input files as argument.

```
#!/bin/sh

file=${1}

sed -n /foo/p ${file} > foo.csv
sed -n /bar/p ${file} > bar.csv
sed -n /baz/p ${file} > baz.csv
```

Comment: Couldn't I do `sh print.sh < stackoverflow.csv`? The file name will change so I don't want to 'hard code' it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with grep in a loop where you don't need to provideeach term in advance. Assuming a bash shell:

```
for i in $(sort stackoverflow.csv | uniq); do grep $i testfile > $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

The `w` command in `sed` allows you to write to a named file.

```
sed -n -e '/foo/wfoo.csv' -e '/bar/wbar.csv' \
    -e '/baz/wbaz.csv' stackoverflow.csv
```

Not all `sed` dialects accept multiple `-e` arguments; a multi-line string with the commands separated by newlines may be the most portable solution.

```
sed -n '/foo/wfoo.csv
    /bar/wbar.csv
    /baz/wbaz.csv' stackoverflow.csv
```

This examines the input file just once, and writes out the matching lines as it proceeds through the file.

To create a script which accepts one or more file names as arguments, replace the hard-coded file name with `"$@"`.

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -n ... "$@"
```

Comment: Can you show me this in a shell script where I don't need to specify the input file in the script?

Comment: That's a trivial adaptation. `"$1"` is the script's first argument and `"$@"` are all the arguments.